# Kendo UI - How to make specific fields readonly on edit while on create its editable in kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a question on how to implement the readonly on edit in kendo UI.
see below for detailed explanation

I have the following Fields:

FirstName (editable on create) (editable on edit)
LastName (editable on create) (editable on edit)
UserName (editable on create) (readonly on edit)
Email (editable on create) (editable on edit)
TelephoneNumber (editable on create) (editable on edit)
PreWin2KUserName (not editable on create)(readonly on edit)

Using the Kendo UI Grid Reference Link
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html

plus this to implement
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/making-column-as-readonly-on-update-and-editable-on-insert-in-grid.aspx

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881484/make-cell-readonly-in-kendo-grid-if-condition-is-met?lq=1

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [edit event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-edit) of the Grid. If the model is not new i.e. the user is editing (not creating) the record you attach the readonly attribute to the desired input element.

```
$('#yourGrid').kendoGrid({
     // ...
     edit: function(e) {
         if (!e.model.isNew()){
             // make sure the UserName id selector is correct in your code
             // (it should be, for a regular text input)
             $('#UserName').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
         }
     }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check on this and give feedback.