# Conditionally editable kendo cell in grid_AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to make cells in Kendo grid conditionally editable. For example, when Status column is 0, only then Value column should be editable. Here is what I tried:

```
{       field: "Quantity",
        title: "Value",
        width: "100px",
        template: '#= kendo.toString(Quantity, "n2")#  #=UnitOfMeasure#',
        attributes: {style: "text-align: right;"},
       **editable:"#if(Status == '0') {#true#} else{#false#}#",**
    },
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make cell readonly in Kendo Grid if condition is met](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881484/make-cell-readonly-in-kendo-grid-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the edit event of the Grid for this purpose. This forum post will help you:

[Kendo UI Grid Conditional editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067930/kendo-ui-grid-conditional-editing)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply conditional editing at grid Init, but you can surely have a condition on edit event and control the feature there as below (I have used Razor, so the code is using Razor):

> .Events(events => events
>            .Edit("ShowBookingPopup")

```
 function ShowBookingPopup(e) {
    // Your custom condition to allow/block editing 
    if (true) { //Access Model via e.Model
    .... Your logic
    } else { // condition incorrect
       e.preventDefault();
    }

 }
```