# Kendo grid cells as regular textboxes instead of kendoNumericTextboxes

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to populate an editable kendo grid. In all examples I see e.g. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline , the inline editor cells seem to be normally displayed as kendoNumericTextBox.

I'm looking e.g. at this example (approved answer) [Kendo UI Grid Conditional editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067930/kendo-ui-grid-conditional-editing), where it is accessed in the following way:

```
e.container.find("input[name=DiscountPercentageMRC]").data("kendoNumericTextBox")
```

Apart from this jsFiddle I cannot access the numeric textboxes in this way. Where can the problem be?

Comment: No, it is just a normal HTML5 input text with kendo UI style applied. `<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="ProductName" required="required" data-bind="value:ProductName">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the two versions of the question, I assume that you are asking why sometimes the edit textboxes are Kendo UI textboxes (e.g. NumericTextBox or Kendo-UI-styled input), and sometimes are plain inputs.

When the Kendo UI MVC Grid wrapper is used, the editor widgets depend on the following:

- the default ASP.NET MVC editors for specific data field types.
- the editor template files placed in the `/EditorTemplates/` folder(s).

Probably you don't have the Kendo UI editor template files in your application, that's why no Kendo UI widgets are used in edit mode. Please verify that.

The built-in Kendo UI editor templates are avaialble in the `wrappers/aspnetmvc/EditorTemplates` folder of the "UI for ASP.NET MVC" installation.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/introduction#distribution-contents

Here is how to use them or create your own editor templates:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates

After you have the Kendo UI widgets being used as editors, you can access them in the Grid's `edit` event like this:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/access-editor-control

Plain textbox editors and Kendo-UI-styles plain inputs are accessed as standard `input` elements via the respective field name. No `.data('kendoWidgetName')` method is needed:

```
var productNameTextBox = e.container.find("[name=ProductName]");
```

Comment: thank you dimodi it is useful. I followed your advice and added the templates to Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder - now (or I believe only now) I get textboxes as kendo elements, but numeric text boxes still as plain text boxes. Some ideas?

Comment: thank you. It turns out that for integer type I needed to explicitly add [UiHint("Integer")] annotation to my viewModel and for decimal define a new editorTemplate, which does not come out the box. Other number types work without data annotations based on kendo supplied editorTemplates, a bit strange.