# Kendo Grid : how to use a column template so editor always available?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a grid that has a column where the editor is always available, so that editing the cell is a "one click" process. By this I mean rather than having to click on the cell to first switch to edit mode, and then select from the combo box, the user can straight away (using the mouse) click on the combobox down arrow to open it and select a value.

I thought I could do this using a column template (as opposed to editor) as follows...

```
function createComboTemplate(dataItem) {
   var tmpl = '<input style="width:100%" ' +
    'kendo-combo-box ' +
    'k-data-text-field="\'display\'" ' +
    'k-data-value-field="\'rego\'" ' +
    'k-data-source="getCarList()"' +
    'k-value="dataItem.rego"' +
    'k-on-change="handleDDLChange(kendoEvent, dataItem)"/>';

   return tmpl;
 }
```

Full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/1uk2kg79/1/)

The above shows the combo box, however as soon as I click on it, the cell goes to a text edit field. So I thought that perhaps the cell going into edit mode was causing this, so I set the columns editable property to false , but this made no difference.

IF I set the whole grid's editable property to false, **then** when I click on the combo box, it stays there, however it is empty.

In this example, the combobox data source is via a function, I also tried setting directly to a global list object (incase it was the function call that was the problem), but this didn't work either.

So, I Have a couple of related questions here.

The first, is to do with the property names in the template. 
When I create a combobox in straight code, I have as follows (as in the above demo)

```
function createCombo(container, options, data) {
    var dataField = options.field.split('.');
    var fieldName = dataField[0];
    var input = $('<input/>')
    input.appendTo(container)
    input.kendoComboBox({
       autoBind: true,
       filter: "contains",
       placeholder: "select...",
       suggest: true,
       dataTextField: "display",
       dataValueField: "rego",
       dataSource: data,
       value: options.model[fieldName].rego,
       change: function (e) {
         var dataItem = this.dataItem();
         options.model[fieldName]['rego'] = dataItem.rego;
         options.model.set(fieldName + '.display', dataItem.display);
        }
     });
    }
```

So the above snippet has properties like "dataTextField", and "dataSource", etc, but when I created the template, from another example of templates I found, it seemed to use names like "k-data-text-field" and "k-data-source".

Is there any doco, or rules on how these field names map in the "markup" that is used in the templates (I could not find any)? It appear that the property names are prefixed with "k-data", and then the camelcase names converted to the "dash" syntax (similar to what angular does). IS this just the rules that we follow? If not then perhaps my problems are the syntax above is incorrect.

The other question is of course, what have I done wrong to cause the 2 problems

1. The combobox disappears when I click on it (unless the whole, grid is set to non editable)
2. Why the combo has no data

Or am I going about this the wrong way.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It appear that the property names are prefixed with "k-data", and then
>   the camelcase names converted to the "dash" syntax (similar to what
>   angular does). IS this just the rules that we follow?

Yes - the documentation is [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/data-attribute-initialization).

> The combobox disappears when I click on it (unless the whole, grid is
>   set to non editable)

This is because the column is editable, so it gets replaced by the default editor. You can prevent this from happening using the technique I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20881973/2001735). I also used it in the demo.

> Why the combo has no data

Your template doesn't work; it should be something like this:

```
  var tmpl = '<input style="width:100%" ' +
    'kendo-combo-box ' +
    'k-data-text-field="\'display\'" ' +
    'k-data-value-field="\'rego\'" ' +
    'k-data-source="dataItem.carSource"' +
    'k-value="dataItem.car.rego" />';
```

and for that to work, you need to give each data item a reference to the car data (you can't execute a function there, the template is evaluated against a kendo.data.Model instance).

(updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1uk2kg79/2/))

Comment: Thank you very much Lars! That works perfect. I am studying your technique of extending and adding the event to the grid (together with the doco on this). Very impressive and it certainly does seem to be very powerful to be able to do this. I have quite a bit of learning to do. Thanks again.

Comment: just going over this, I just realised there is the one thing missing the call when the value is updated in the combo (so I can set the underlying model data). I added in the call k-on-change="handleDDLChange(kendoEvent, dataItem) here.. http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/1uk2kg79/3 but the handleDDLChange is not called. Have I got the wrong syntax here?

Comment: yeah, the change function is not in scope, so like the car source, you'd need to create a reference for it on the dataItem: http://jsfiddle.net/1uk2kg79/4/

Comment: Ok, great thank you very much once gain!. I do have one more piece to the puzzle (which I thought I would be able to figure out once I had this event called). I want to set the selected value. When using a combo as a editor, you previously showed I can do this via .. options.model[fieldName]['rego'] = dataItem.rego; I have looked everywhere in both arguments but just cannot find the field name (I can see the values, prev values etc, but not the field name (even tried passing this into the callback). Would find this so I can st the Model (I assume the dataItem is the model)? Cheers

Comment: Great, yes I see. Thank you very much for that. Now I can set it, using the values from kendoEvent.sender._selectedValue;and kendoEvent.sender._prev (weird names, but the appear to have the selected values). Cheers again

Comment: I don't think you should use the underscore vars; use .value() for the selected value; not sure what you want with _prev

Comment: Yes, they don't look right, but I looked through every property in the 2 arguments (kendoEvent and dataItem), and just could not find a value() (or selectedValue)?

Comment: I meant sender.value() where sender is the combobox widget

Comment: same with e.sender.select(), e.sender.text(), depending on what you need

Comment: They are much better (than accessing the "private" looking members). Cheers for that!