# How to disable edit from kendo editable grid dynamically?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I would like to disable edit from only first cell of kendo edit-able grid and I am doing something like below. Actually I am trying to remove a datepicker 
from first cell of kendo grid as it is not required to be there. so I am using below and this code removes datepicker from grid but it still shows a text box.
I should be able to remove it completely.

```
  function onGridEditing(e) {
        var gridbody = $("#EditableGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var gridData = gridbody.dataSource.view();
        var currentUid = gridData[0].uid;
        var Date = gridData[0].Date;
        var currenRow = gridbody.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
        //var firstCell = currenRow.find('td:not(:empty):first');
        //firstCell.find('.k-select').remove();
        //alert(firstCell.val());
        currenRow.find('.k-select').remove();// this removes the datepicker but it is still showing textbox when user click on the row for edit.
        currenRow.find(".editDate").remove();

ALso I tried to apply a css over there so that it hide datepicker but not working
//$("#EditableGrid").data("kendoGrid")._data[0].addClass('hideMe');
    }

<style>

   .hideMe {
        /*visibility: hidden;*/
        border: none !important;
        background-color: none !important;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: On edit event you can just hide whole column if it is not being used `grid.hideColumn(0);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881484/make-cell-readonly-in-kendo-grid-if-condition-is-met

Answer (score 1):

You could disable editing of a particular column in the model of the dataSource. For example:

```js
model: {
    fields: {
        ProductID: {
            //this field will not be editable (default value is true)
            editable: false
        }
    }
}
```

source: [Telerik Forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/disable-editing-of-a-grid-column)

**Edit:** To do it dynamically:

```js
var model = $("#EditableGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(currentUid);
if (model) {
    model.fields["ProductID"].editable = false;
}
```

Comment: But this will disable whole column. I just want to disable edit on just first cell of a row and not in others.