# Disable row in kendo gird

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid having few columns, first column is rolename and other columns are add,edit,view and checkboxes below them...i am giving access of add,edit,view based on role. what i want to do is I want to disable a row which is having role name as 'Admin', means add,edit,view functionality of admin role shouldn't be changed from UI and all three checkboxes(add,edit,view) of that row should be disabled, however other rows can be editable. I want to achieve this on button click. i got the table row using following code, don't know how to proceed further.

```
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function () {
                    return $(this).text() == "Admin";
                }).closest("tr");
```

any help please?

Comment: Can you provide a working demo in http://dojo.telerik.com ?

Comment: actually it is quite complex code...around 2000 to 2500 lines..

Comment: Just build the grid with like 5 row of fake data, but reproducing the checkboxes as you have in your real code.. something simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make cell readonly in Kendo Grid if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881484/make-cell-readonly-in-kendo-grid-if-condition-is-met)